# Keyerror after looping a dictionary

Tags: loops, dictionary, keyerror

I am doing an api call to a large database that sends back data in JSON format. Since the data is that big, the database sends the JSON data in separate batches, each batch containing an nextPageUrl: to the next batch. I want to loop/crawl through the batches, collect the URL of each batch, store them in a list, and then loop that list again to parse all the JSON data. Then populate my own SQLITE database with the parse results. However, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Database_download_v2.py", line 52, in <module>
    if (len(json_dict['nextPageUrl']) > 0): 
KeyError: 'nextPageUrl'
```

The code I use is:

```
load_page = requests.get(form_response_tree, headers=headers).content
page_decode = load_page.decode()
json_dict = json.loads(page_decode)
url_subseq_page = json_dict['nextPageUrl']
url_list = list()
url_list.append(url_subseq_page)

for all_pages in url_list:
    load_page = requests.get(all_pages, headers=headers).content
    page_decode = load_page.decode()
    json_dict = json.loads(page_decode)
    if (len(json_dict['nextPageUrl']) > 0):
        url_subseq_page = json_dict['nextPageUrl']
        url_list.append(url_subseq_page)
    else:
        continue
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Without seeing some of the JSON response it's hard to answer this other than the key does not exist or you are missing some keys before nextPageUrl.   .get() is a dict method though that can ignore keyerrors and will return None if not found.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't have anything in the list so it will technically not work.

### Solution

```
url_list = ["putstringsinthislist"]
```